# Creating 2-way binding for elements created after initial compiliation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I created a directive that dynamically creates a form based on a json from the server. I'm trying to add `ng-model` attribute to the various input elements so that I'll be able to use the input values after the user has typed them in and clicked submit. The `ng-model` attribute seems to be added but 2-way databinding doesn't work.

**EDIT: I'm calling buildForm from within the link function as seen below:**

```
function link(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
    //asyc request to the server, data here is a json object from the server
    getMovieDataStructure({
        onSuccess: (data) => {
            scope.mdb = data;
            buildForm(scope.mdb, elem);
        },
        onFail: (res) => {
            console.log("ERROR getting it");
        }
    });            
}
```

Here is some of the code from in the directive:

```
//mdb is an array of objects describing the form requirments
function buildForm(mdb, formElement) {
    for(var i=0; i < mdb.length; i++) {
        if(mdb[i].type == 'string') {
            if(mdb[i].maxLength && mdb[i].maxLength > 1024) {
                //if maxLength > 1024 put a text area instead
                formElement.append(createTextArea({
                    id: mdb[i].fieldName,
                    placeholder: mdb[i].fieldName
                }));
            } else {
                //add input field to the form
                formElement.append(createTextInput({
                    id: mdb[i].fieldName,
                    placeholder: mdb[i].fieldName
                }));
            }
        } else if(){
            //some more cases
        }

        formElement.append("<br>");
    }
    //...some more code...
}

//one of the functions to create an input element
function createTextInput(data) {
    var elem = angular.element("<input>");
    elem.attr("type", "text");
    elem.attr("id", data.id);
    elem.attr("ng-model", data.id);
    elem.attr("placeholder", data.placeholder);

    return elem;
}
```

For example, a result of an input element on the html page could look like this:

```
<input placeholder="movie_name" ng-model="movie_name" id="movie_name" type="text"> </input>
```

And if I'll put the same tag directly to in the html file the 2-way binding works great.

What am missing here? Is there a better way to do this and I'm just overcomplicating things?

Comment: if you are using ```$http``` for getting data from the server then it should update the model in view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wdanda mentioned, since the directive adds DOM elements, it needs to be compiled afterwards to let angular be aware of the changes

**Short answer** is that the line `buildForm(scope.mdb, elem);` has been changed to `$compile(buildForm(scope.mdb, elem).contents())(scope);` and `'$compile'` was added to the directive's list of dependencies.

**Long explanation:**

`buildForm(scope.mdb,elem)` returns the element of the directive (so actually adding `$compile(elem.contents())(scope);` after `buildForm` would be equivilant), `.contents()` on an angular wraped element returns all of that element children.

That means that `$compile(buildForm(scope.mdb, elem).contents())` tells angular to compile all the children of the directive's element, after `buildForm` has added some elements to it (and which some of them have directives of their own.

The call for `.contents()` is important because:

> we only compile .childNodes so that we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves

(from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

The `$compile()` function returns a linking function that needs to be called with a scope to link to. So adding `(scope)` at the end will call that returned function.

A more clear (though slightly less elegant) way to write that code, would be:

```
var element = buildForm(scope.mdb, elem); //buildForm returns an angular wraped element
var linking = $compile(element); // $compile returns a linking  function
linking(scope); //linking is functions that takes a scope object
                //and needs to be run after compilation
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere after you update the form you will need to call $compile, otherwise angular will not be aware of your changes. See:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: I didn't mention before that I'm calling building the form from the link function. Will it make more sense (and maybe save me the need to call `$compile` if I'll do it from the template function?

Comment: If you can do it from template function it should work, however template function must return a string, not a DOM tree

Answer (score 0):

Something to try would be to call $rootScope.apply() after you call the buildform method maybe. What may be happening is that you are making all these changes to the DOM after the digest cycle completes and angular won't know about your changes until the next cycle happens.

So in your case it will be:
        buildForm(scope.mdb, elem);
        **scope.$apply();**

Answer (score 0):

Thing is digest loop needs to be called explicitly in your case cause angular is unaware of the change made.

USE:

```
buildForm(scope.mdb, elem); 
scope.$apply();
```

OR

But there is a better way for using $apply:

```
scope.$apply(buildForm(scope.mdb,elem));
```

The difference is that in the first version, we are updating the values outside the angular context so if that throws an error, Angular will never know.

Comment: I am getting the following error: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest (did it the second way, and the error stack trace is pointing to that line)